# Dotnet Nuke Change Skin

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've just started using dotnet nuke (v6.2) today. I've uploaded a new skin and applied it. I've also added a new page to the website. When I'm logged in as admin I can see thenew page and it's all styled with the new skin. However, when I browse the site without login it's styled using the default dark knight skin and I can't see my new page.

Can anyone please tell me what step I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd changed the skin for the site under the appearance menu - the skin for the individual pages was still set to Dark Knight. I changed this to be site default and now all is good :)

Comment: So, the skin had changed for some pages that required authentication, but the public-facing pages hadn't changed?  That does sound confusing...

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possibilities for why you'd see a different skin when you're logged in.  First, if you're using DotNetNuke professional, you could have page caching turned on, and need to wait for the cache to clear (though changing the skin should clear it automatically).  Secondly, it could be that there's an error in the skin when you're logged out (if there's some custom code in the skin which determines whether you have an account or not).  Check the log viewer to see if there are any errors being logged when you visit the site logged out.

Comment: I'm using the free version. I've checked the event viewer, no exceptions so still a bit stuck.

Comment: I just tried uploading another new skin but I get exactly the same problem with this also?